# Loop data in PHP POST based on ID

Tags: php

I have a form (https://jsfiddle.net/jr3gnbsu/) with multiple rows/columns and I'd like to update my SQL table with this data.

***HTML form snippet:***

```
<tr class="row-id-139">
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text" name="account_dob_139" value="01/01/2001"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text" name="account_name_139" value="John Johnson"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-id-140">
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text" name="account_dob_140" value="01/01/2000"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text" name="account_name_140" value="Jack Thomson"></td>
</tr>
```

***PHP script:***

I have a `update.php` script which just has `var_dump($_POST)`, it outputs the following:

```
array(4) {
  ["account_dob_139"]=> string(10) "01/01/2001"
  ["account_name_139"]=> string(12) "John Johnson"
  ["account_dob_140"]=> string(10) "01/01/2000"
  ["account_name_140"]=> string(12) "Jack Thomson"
}
```

Basically `139` & `140` refer to the ID so I'd love to loop through each row of the table in my PHP script and update a SQL table row.

How is this possible?

Comment: Sounds like a plan! `foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)` then an [`explode()`](https://php.net/explode) after `_` should do the trick.

Comment: If you can change the HTML, consider [HTMHell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65529150/732284). Much easier if PHP can do all the work of splitting and accumulating for you.

Comment: @rid Fortunately I do control the HTML so that's good news. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use array instead:

```
<tr class="row-id-139">
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text" name="account_dob[139]" value="01/01/2001"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text" name="account_name[139]" value="John Johnson"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-id-140">
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text" name="account_dob[140]" value="01/01/2000"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text" name="account_name[140]" value="Jack Thomson"></td>
</tr>
```

And in your PHP:

```
foreach ($_POST['account_dob'] as $id => $dob) {
    $name = $_POST['account_name'][$id];
    echo "$dob, $name";
}
```